# Wordpress CI in Gitlab

Tags: wordpress, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is there any reference of Implementing WorPress **(WP_UnitTestCase)** using Gitlab CI?

I have already tried configuring the `.gitlab-ci.yml`, it implements the build, but no test are runned.

This is the .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: php:5.6

variables:
  # Configure mysql service (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
  MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress_tests
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql

before_script:
  # Install dependencies
  - bash ci/docker_install.sh wordpress_tests root mysql tutum-wordpress latest

stages:
  - test

# test:PHP5.3:MySQL:
#   image: tetraweb/php:5.3
#   script:
#   - phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml.dist

test:PHP5.4:MySQL:
  image: tetraweb/php:5.4
  services:
  - tutum/wordpress:latest
  script:
  - phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml.dist

# test:PHP5.6:MySQL:
#   image: php:5.6
#   script:
#   - phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml.dist

# test:PHP7:MySQL:
#   image: php:7
#   script:
#   - phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml.dist
```

Comment: It seems like you are asking for a tutorial which is off-topic at SO. I'd suggest you rather extend your question with all the information: what you tried, the content of your  `.gitlab-ci.yml`, which part fails, the build log, etc.

Comment: @cascaval I will update with the code, but it doesn't work. I asked because I considered important for the WP community to know how to implement CI, in a free tool like gitlab.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I got it working for me, you can see the tests for PHP5.3 through PHP7.0 are running properly for a test plugin I created [here](https://gitlab.com/Nikchavan/test-wp-plugin)

This is how my [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/Nikchavan/test-wp-plugin/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) looks like. and the shell script to setup the environment is [here](https://gitlab.com/Nikchavan/test-wp-plugin/blob/master/bin/install_gitlab_tests.sh)

To use this in your project,just copy the `.gitlab-ci.yml`, `bin/install_gitlab_tests.sh` to your project.

Comment: It worked great, now is build, and testing correctly :)

Comment: the answer worked ok. But nowadays gitlab shows me this error: Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/testcase.php on line 15

Comment: WP CLI now supports Gitlab CI in it's scaffold command, This should create all the correct files for your plugin/theme - http://wp-cli.org/commands/scaffold/plugin-tests/

Comment: I have make the scaffold with WP CLI however the error persists 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase', do you have any idea why this error persists? @NikhilChavan

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Looks like it was a wordpress compatibility problem with phpunit 6.0. Fixed by downgranding phpunit to 5.6. See: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/3802

Comment: I see, I'm using the tetraweb/php:7.0 image, any other image for Wordpress CI that has the phpunit 5.6?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15650233)

Comment: @StevenV I'm not using Wordpress CI so I've just changed the composer.json requirement for the plugin I'm testing.

Comment: @thebluefox you are right, but I didn't have enough privileges to comment or review so I started this only to try to help the fellow with similar problem. Plus I don't know if the solution is related to Wordpress CI.

Comment: @DanielBadahHernandes I'm using a docker image tetraweb, it installs phpunit by default (it could be that install phpunit 6.0 instead of 5.6), so I just wanted to know if there is another docker image that installs phpunit 5.6 by default.